# Update data in datatable using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

How to edit the column value of a datatable in c#.
The below shown is my Datatable.

[image]

We have to update the column values. The values after the decimal point should be replaced with "00". There is no condition for the updation. we have to convert the values without decimal point also. It shold also followed by "00". (All values should be in the same format). Therefore the table will look like this.

[image]

I think Linq is the best choice than iterating the Datatable. How can I implement this.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: linq is a syntactic sugar also iterates all rows behind the scenes

Comment: I'm not sure which framework your utilizing, but why can't you force them into the above format by doing `ToString("#,##0.00")`.  Assuming they're a decimal type. Then it will force them into the same format when they come out of the database?